# Protractor : Selection of an element from Popup value

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

We have some textboxes where the value needs to be selected from a popup list. The elements and the popup are like this:

[image: PopUp and Element]

The related html codes are as follows:

```
<div _ngcontent-c6="" class="col px-0">
  <input _ngcontent-c6="" aria-multiline="false" autocapitalize="off" 
    autocorrect="off" class="form-control ng-dirty ng-valid open ng-touched"
    formcontrolname="ESYSITENAME" id="esySiteName" name="" placeholder="" 
    role="combobox" type="text" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list"
    aria-expanded="true" aria-activedescendant="ngb-typeahead-2-0" 
    aria-owns="ngb-typeahead-2">

  <ngb-typeahead-window class="dropdown-menu show ng-star-inserted" 
    role="listbox" id="ngb-typeahead-2" style="top: 39px; left: 0px;">

    <button class="dropdown-item ng-star-inserted active" role="option"
       type="button" id="ngb-typeahead-2-0">

      <ngb-highlight _ngcontent-c6="" _nghost-c25="" class="ng-star-inserted">
          <span _ngcontent-c25="" class="ngb-highlight ng-star-inserted">
              Bull Run Elementary School
          </span>
      </ngb-highlight>
    </button>

  </ngb-typeahead-window>

</div>
```

I have tried to select the Popup element using different strategies like:

```
let EsyNamePopup = $('#ngb-typeahead-2-0 > ngb-highlight > span');
await helpers.waitForElementVisibility(EsyNamePopup);
await helpers.clickWhenClickable(EsyNamePopup);

// or following way:
let EsyNamePopup = element(by.cssContainingText('span', 'Bull Run Elementary School,));
await EsyNamePopup.click();
```

None of them worked but got following error messages:

> NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, #ngb-typeahead-2-0 > ngb-highlight > span)

Is there a better strategy to select these elements?

Comment: You might want to have a look at waitForWindowCount in hetznercloud's protractor-test-helper. And then you may well need to get that popup's handle and switch to it before you can click anything in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try a long sleep before click on the pop option. If long sleep can fix your issue, it proves your wait function `waitForElementVisibility` has issue or you not give sufficient wait time.

```
await $('input#esySiteName').sendKeys('Bull');

await browser.sleep(15000) 

await $('#ngb-typeahead-2-0 > ngb-highlight > span').click()
```

Answer (score -1):

You could set up breakpoints and debug your code by following the steps in here.
http://www.protractortest.org/#/debugging

Might want to verify if sendkeys will initiate the typeahead popup or if element needs to be focused in order for that.